# Is there a better way to tag this question without 4 platform specific tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, asking-questions, etiquette

I've been a Delphi coder for quite a while now, using the [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) and [delphi-xe2](/questions/tagged/delphi-xe2) tags quite often. Delphi XE2 and above versions (XE5 now) include a new platform called [firemonkey](/questions/tagged/firemonkey), which allows for mobile development.

Here is [one example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462023/whats-the-purpose-in-being-able-to-resize-a-form-for-ios) which I asked, using 4 tags just to describe the specific platform.

If I were to ask such a question specific to this new language, I would have to include the following tags:

- delphi
- delphi-xe2 (or whatever version)
- firemonkey
- ios (or whatever platform)
- Room enough for one other tag

Now, as you can see, such a specific tagging would leave only room enough for 1 specific tag, since the rest is related to the specific platform.

Is there a more appropriate way to tag such questions leaving room for more than one specific tag?

The problem is, if I were to exclude the [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) tag, it would not hit the radar of the people monitoring Delphi questions (like I commonly do). Yet, if I exclude the [delphi-xe2](/questions/tagged/delphi-xe2) tag, it wouldn't relate to the version I'm using, which does make a huge difference. I obviously need to mention the [firemonkey](/questions/tagged/firemonkey) tag, that's the whole code platform (as opposed to [vcl](/questions/tagged/vcl)). Then of course the OS platform being iOS, therefore the tag [ios](/questions/tagged/ios).

This takes up 4 of the maximum of 5 tags. Which tag is the weakest link?

Comment: If I at least mention [tag:ios], can it be safely assumed that I can exclude [tag:firemonkey]? Since you would obviously need to use Firemonkey in the first place to be able to port to iOS.

Comment: I would not remove any of the mentioned main tags until you urgently need the space for a specific tag. You will need delphi since many users may use it as main filter, the same could be seen for firemonkey. Someone using XE5 only might decide not beeing able to answer the question due to the major differences in firemonkey. Omitting iOS would be a missing information for those who are targeting Android or Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Version specific](/q/85358/212576) tags **should** be avoided unless the problem is actually relevant to it. Thus, you can have an extra tag by not using [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi).

In the [example question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19462023/1190388) you've provided, I don't think you can use any other tags which would be any further relevant to the question. Sure you can use tag such as [screen-size](/questions/tagged/screen-size)
 or maybe [alignment](/questions/tagged/alignment) but they would (*imo*) be irrelevant to the question. So, as I see it; I'd be using the following tags:

- Delphi-xe2 (or simply delphi; whichever you think might be appropriate)
- Firemonkey
- iOS
- resizing
- screen-size

Tagging is still a feature which is too meta and different users have different views about. For example, some users might even chose to tag the question with [devices](/questions/tagged/devices), [form](/questions/tagged/form) and/or create a new [form-size](/questions/tagged/form-size).

All in all, there is no perfect way of tagging questions. You can chose which tags you might think appropriate and other users can add/remove tags as they think appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, in this case, since Firemonkey is still new to the Delphi world, each version of Delphi introduces a new major shift in the platform.

Comment: Delphi XE5 recently introducing Android in the mix.

Comment: @JerryDodge But platforms don't restrict you from building the same application for iOS in a different version, or so I assume. For eg. an iOS application built with XE2 would still work if you build it with XE5 or is it not so?

Comment: The same code base for iOS can also be ported directly to Android. I haven't experimented with this, but yes, I get your point. However, XE2 had very primitive controls, whereas XE5 is much more developed and stable.

Comment: My first time experimenting with a new Firemonkey application, the controls weren't even implemented yet. For example, a simple grid control was just an empty shell, still waiting for the actual grid functionality to be implemented. Then came the updates, which introduced the fresh implementation of these controls. But I'm still on XE2, the original version when Firemonkey was introduced. I have yet to venture into the later versions afterwards.